# Medium or medium-sized?

Tags: meaning, differences, vocabulary, semantics

We say a *medium-sized* pan/book/house, but *medium* height/amount/size.
But I came across an example in Cambridge Advanced learner's Dictionary: "Chop one medium carrot."
I wonder if we can use *medium* instead of *medium-sized* in the above examples, or it is just an exception.

Comment: 'I wanted to know if we can use ...' is a strange way of phrasing your question. If you check on the internet for pairs ("medium pan"; "medium-sized pan" etc) I'm sure you'll find whether both variants are commonly used. You can  check for yourself on the more popular variant in each case for which both are in use. The simplex adjective sometimes sounds less precise, and is sometimes insufficient (a medium person?) but is sometimes the more idiomatic choice (a medium coffee). Here, 'book' and 'house' don't collocate; measures  (size, heat (cooker), weight) rarely allow the '-sized'.

Comment: @Edwin: Are you going to delete that first *medium comment* now you've added a *supersized* one? :)

Comment: ...But probably, 'medium amount' and 'medium-sized amount' are interchangeable. I'd think that food units (cabbage, egg, chicken, apple ...) are used freely with both variants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We say "medium-weight" or medium-whatever when we need to distinguish just what is medium. If I said, "Bob is a medium person", what does that mean? He could be of medium height, medium intelligence, medium sorcery skill level, or many other factors. So I might say, "Bob is a medium-height person."

In context it might be obvious and therefore unnecessary to specify. "What size shirt does Bob where?" "Bob's a medium." "Is your boyfriend rich?" "Oh, he's about medium." Etc.

Sometimes people give additional information when it's not really necessary. If a recipe calls for "three medium carrots", it almost surely means medium size and not medium shade of orange or medium price at the grocery store. Nevertheless people will sometimes say "three medium-size carrots", perhaps just to be absolutely clear, perhaps to be consistent with other statements in the same document, or perhaps for no good reason.